# Can't get external style sheets to work with golang templates

Tags: css, go

Internal CSS works fine but external style sheet isn't working.  I end up with the standard page with no styling showing up.  The templates served just fine except no CSS.

Created a simple app to eliminate some of the variables but the same issue persists.

root of app
C:\workspace\goworkspace\src\practice3\

GOPATH C:\workspace\goworkspace

```
//practice3/main.go
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)

    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

//practice3/static/example.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>A static page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello from a static page</h1>
</body>
</html>

//practice3/stylesheets/main.css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  h1 {
    color: navy;`enter code here`
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
```

No errors, everything seems to work fine (including internal css) except for the external css.

Comment: Is `static/stylesheets/main.css` the correct path to your CSS from your current working directory when you execute the program? Have you checked the network tab in your browser to see what happens with those requests?

Comment: Your `fs` is serving files from the `static` directory, is there where your css lives? *No it's not*.

Comment: That was it, thank you.